# Given $(x-1)^3+3(x-1)^2-2(x-1)-4=a(x+1)^3+b(x+1)^2+c(x+1)+d$, find$(a,b,c,d)$

Tags: polynomials

> Given $(x-1)^3+3(x-1)^2-2(x-1)-4=a(x+1)^3+b(x+1)^2+c(x+1)+d$,
>   find$(a,b,c,d)$

my attempt:
$$(x+1)=(x-1)\frac{(x+1)}{(x-1)}$$
but this seems useless?
I want to use synthetic division but I don't know how

Comment: You could simply substitute $x=y-1$ and expand the LHS.

Comment: The LHS simplifies to $x^3 - 5x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's  $$(x+1-2)^3+3(x+1-2)^2-2(x+1-2)-4=(x+1)^3-3(x+1)^2-2(x+1)+4.$$
Can you end it now?

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

If $F(t)=c_0+c_1t+c_2t^2+\cdots$ then
$$
c_n=\frac1{n!}\left.\frac{d^nF}{dt^n}\right|_{t=0}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

In case you don't know how to solve this most elegantly, there is still the straightforward possibility by expanding both sides. The LHS is given by
$$
x^3-5x,
$$
whereas the RSH is
$$
ax^3 + (3a + b)x^2 + (3a + 2b + c)x + a + b + c + d.
$$